# Envío/recepción de datos, puerto serie por Python

Tags: python, puertos

Estoy intentando enlazar mi programa en python de cálculo de direccionamiento de satélites con el programa de control de rotores rotctld de Hamlib (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/rotctld.8.htm).
He comprobado que cada parte funciona por su cuenta pero a la hora de intentar mandarle datos al puerto serie directamente desde Python he fracasado.

Solo tengo que mandarle ordenes muy simples como:

> -P
> -p XXX.XX XXX.XX (para ordenarle azimut y elevación)

Y otras en el estilo, muy sencillas, pero no consigo transmitirle nada desde Python. Si lo he conseguido desde Putty y mi objetivo es replicar su funcionamiento ¿Alguna idea? Por lo que he estado mirando para este tipo de conexión por socket es muy popular la librería Pyserial (https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/), pero no consigo hacerme a su funcionamiento.

Después de los consejos que me habeis dado he intentado establecer la conexión con:

```
import serial
puerto = "COM3" # tipico en windows X= un entero positivo
baudrate = 9600 #(o el baudrate adecuado/usado en putty)
ser = serial.Serial(port=puerto, baudrate=baudrate)

ser.write(b'p\r\n')

import time
time.sleep(1) # tiempo en segundos. 1 segundo es harto, pero usalo para probar
respuesta_bytes = ser.read() # si sabes la cantidad de bytes recibidos, puedes especificarlo dentro de los parentesis.
# Transforma los bytes en string
respuesta_string = respuesta_bytes.decode('utf-8')
print(respuesta_string)

ser.close()
```

pero siempre me salta el error:

```
SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Acceso denegado.', None, 5)
```

Creo que esto se puede deber a que estoy usando el servidor daemon rigctld que acapara el puerto, ¿existe alguna solución?

Comment: ¿qué has intentado con pyserial?

Comment: He intentado establecer conexion y enviarle órdenes al daemon que tengo funcionando, pero lo mejor que he conseguido es error [WinError 10061]

Comment: me refería al código que estés usando, siempre es mejor poner el código que se intenta.

Comment: Dices `Creo que esto se puede deber a que estoy usando el servidor daemon rigctld que acapara el puerto`. Y en la respuesta que te han dado lo dicen bastante claro: `Importante que no tengas otro código/programa (como putty) usando el puerto`.

Comment: Claro, yo lo que necesito es comunicarme con el servidor daemon solo, no se si para ello tengo que darle otro enfoque al asunto, pero tenia entendido que debía hacerlo a través de un socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, te comento que es importante que siempre subas el código que estás utilizando para facilitar la respuesta de los devs.

Mi recomendación es efectivamente usar Pyserial. Instalalo mediante pip.

En cuanto a su uso, si ya te has podido comunicar mediante Putty, entonces sabes el puerto y el baudrate de tu dispositivo serial. Para crear una conexión via pyserial, parte con:

```
import serial
puerto = "COMX" # tipico en windows X= un entero positivo
baudrate = 9600 #(o el baudrate adecuado/usado en putty)
ser = serial.Serial(port=puerto, baudrate=baudrate)
```

Puedes usar el objeto ser ahora para enviar y recibir. Los métodos son "write" y "read".

Ten en consideración que con python3 necesitas enviar bytes (no strings) entonces si quieres enviar un comando de texto tipo "HOLA" debes mandarlo como:

```
ser.write(b'HOLA')
```

Obs: a veces es necesario mandar un \r = CR (Carriage Return) y/o \n = LF (Line Feed), depende del dispositivo serial. En ese caso seria:

```
ser.write(b'HOLA\r\n') #en caso de requerir CR+LF
```

Para leer la respuesta, a veces (no siempre) es necesario un pequeño delay, asi que te recomiendo usar time.sleep:

```
# continuación del código anterior
import time
time.sleep(1) # tiempo en segundos. 1 segundo es harto, pero usalo para probar
respuesta_bytes = ser.read() # si sabes la cantidad de bytes recibidos, puedes especificarlo dentro de los parentesis.
# Transforma los bytes en string
respuesta_string = respuesta_bytes.decode('utf-8')
print(respuesta_string)
```

Finalmente, cierra la comunicación con el puerto:

```
ser.close()
```

Obs: importante que no tengas otro código/programa (como putty) usando el puerto. No se pueden realizar conexiones en paralelo en Windows.

Te recomiendo leer sobre la librería pyserial para más metodos específicos que puedan aplicar en tu proyecto.

Saludos